# Flutter equivalents to `View::onAttachedToWindow` and `View::onDetachedFromWindow`

Tags: android, dart, flutter

What are Flutter equivalents to Android's `View::onAttachedToWindow` and `View::onDetachedFromWindow`?

Basically, in Flutter, how to determine if user can see a particular widget on screen or is it covered, for example, with another screen on top?

Comment: There's no generic events. What is your use-case? Scroll view?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter seem to have limited lifecycle events. Maybe what you're looking for can be achieved by overriding `initState()` and `deactivate()`. Checkout widget lifecycle [here](https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the link, but none of those callbacks is suitable.